# Disable external build in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: intellij-idea

How can one disable external build mode in IntelliJ IDEA 13.

Is this option missing? It was obvious in the previous version (12).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is missing in the sense that you only have one option--to use external build. They removed the other compiler mode.